# how to create connection string in .net 6 winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, connection-string

I have created winform project in .net 6 c#, but i didn't find any App.json or appsetting.json in solution.
Can any body help me to add connection string.
[image]

Should it work if I copy appsetting.json file from another project?

Comment: You can always hard code the connection string into  the program.

Answer (score 4):

In a Winforms application, the configuration data is stored in the app.config file. This file is renamed when you build the application in YourAppName.exe.config and should be distributed with your application.

So you need to add the Application Configuration File to your project via

```
Project => Add => New Item => Application Configuration File.
```

Now you have an XML file in your project root named app.config and you can edit it adding values to some predefined Sections:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="Title" value="MyApp"/>
    </appSettings>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="MyConn" connectionString="server=localhost;database=MyAppDb;Trusted_Connection=Yes"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Next you can use these information inside your winforms application like this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Title"];
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConn"].ConnectionString;
    Label l = new Label();  
    l.Text = constr;
    this.Controls.Add(l);
}
```

There is a [very old post here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19675/Cracking-the-Mysteries-of-NET-2-0-Configuration#duplicate=0) that explain very well this system. Not sure if it is still totally applicable to Winforms in Net6 but probably it is worth to read

Comment: Is there any problem in hard coding the connection string into the program?

Comment: It is not a problem, but you are unable to change destination without recompiling whole program: Imagine you deploy that somewhere into production and after few months server (database) explodes. So you will start a new instance with different name/IP... and now you must to recompile whole program and deploy it, for changing single string value.

Comment: NO DON'T DO THAT. This forces you to add this string everywhere when you need it and even if you manage to centralize it in some way there is still the problem that you don't know how specific could be the client situation and you don't want to recompile your app just because your client has a server with a different name